# Store cron log in timedate file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I have this code currently:

```
echo "20 0 * * * cd /var/www/test/ && ./prog >> /var/log/program.log" >> mycron
```

This works fine, but now I want to store it in a a timedated file each time in the format like this:

```
program_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.log
```

Can anyone tell me how I can do this? I think I need to use the date variable but im not really sure how to implement it.

Comment: `date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"` . Do you want to rename the program.log with the timestamp or the mycron file?

Comment: @rahul The log please

Comment: thanks. It's obvious from your question. My bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You can use the date variable.

```
echo "20 0 * * * cd /var/www/test/ && ./prog >> /var/log/program_$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").log" >> mycron
```

Comment: You should use single quote here: `+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`